# Calling multiple api swiftui without using dispatchgroup

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I wanted to call like 4 apis, then once api count and api index is equal then loader will be dismissed. The problem is the loader sometimes gets stuck.

```
func callApiTest() {
        
        isMainLoading.toggle()
        
        print("Start Fetching")
        
        let cohortId = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "cohortId")
        
        let apiItems = [
            ApiModel(id: 1, apiName: "user/get/x/0?cohort_id=\(cohortId)"),
            ApiModel(id: 2, apiName: "trainings/xx/0?cohort_id=\(cohortId)"),
            ApiModel(id: 3, apiName: "survey/get/xxx/0?cohort_id=\(cohortId)"),
            ApiModel(id: 4, apiName: "user/lowest/xxxx/0?cohort_id=\(cohortId)"),
        ]
        
        if apiCountIndex <= apiCount {
            for item in apiItems {
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: getRequestConfig(endPoint: item.apiName)) {data, _, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("parser error = \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    } else {
                    
                        switch (item.id)  {
                          case 1:
                            if data != nil{
                                do {
                                    let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode(ParticipantModel.self, from: data!)
                                    let items = decoder.response
                                    for item in items {
                                        let entity = ParticipantEntity(context: dataController.container.viewContext)
                                        entity.id = Int64(item.id)
                                        entity.first_name = item.first_name
                                        entity.last_name = item.last_name
                                    }
                                    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(items.count, forKey: "pCounts")
                                    dataController.save()
                                    print("Success Saving Participant Data")
                                } catch {
                                    print(error)
                                }
                            }
                          case 2:
                            if data != nil {
                                do {
                                    let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode(TrainingModel.self, from: data!)
                                    let items = decoder.response
                                    for item in items {
                                        let entity = TrainingEntity(context: dataController.container.viewContext)
                                        entity.training_id = Int64(item.training_id)
                                        entity.group_name = item.columns.group_name
                                        entity.group_id = Int16(item.columns.group_id ?? 0
                                    }
                                    dataController.save()
                                    print("Success Saving Training Data")
                                } catch {
                                    print(error)
                                }
                            }
                        case 3:
                          do {
                              let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode(ParticipantVisitLogModel.self, from: data!)
                              let items = decoder.response
                              for item in items {
                                  let entity = ParticipantVisitLogEntity(context: dataController.container.viewContext)
                                  entity.id = Int16(item.id)
                                  entity.visit_id = Int16(item.visit_id)
                                  entity.type_of_survey = item.type_of_survey
                                  entity.survey_id = Int16(item.survey_id)   
                              }
                              dataController.save()
                              print("Success Saving Participant Visit Log Data")
                          } catch {
                              print(error)
                          }
                        case 4:
                          do {
                              let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode(GroupModel.self, from: data!)
                              let items = decoder.response
                              for item in items {
                                  let entity = GroupEntity(context: dataController.container.viewContext)
                                  entity.id = Int16(item.id)
                                  entity.name = item.name
                              }
                              dataController.save()
                              print("Success Group Data")
                          } catch {
                              print(error)
                          }
                        default:
                            print("DEFAULT")
                            print("DONE CALLING ALL APIS..!")
                            isMainLoading.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }.resume()
                print("XXXXXX")
                print("API Called = \(item.apiName)")
                print("Api Count = \(apiCount)" + " Api Index = \(apiCountIndex)")
                apiCountIndex += 1
            }
        }else{
            isMainLoading.toggle()
            print("DONEEEEEEEE")
        }
    }
```

I used the normal loop to call api the problem is the loader sometimes is stopping. and the logic for  if apiCountIndex <= apiCount {} is not working.

Comment: The alternative of `DispatchGroup` is `async/await`. Be aware that `DONEEEEEEEE` is printed immediately a long time – in terms of computer speed – before the first network request returns some data. And where does `apiCount` come from?

Comment: apiCount is a global variable with a constant value like 4

Answer (score 0):

This code can be hugely simplified by switching from completion blocks to async/await…

```
func callApiTest() async throws {
    
    isMainLoading = true
    
    print("Start Fetching")
    
    let cohortId = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "cohortId")
    
    let apiItems = [
        ApiModel(id: 1, apiName: "user/get/x/0?cohort_id=\(cohortId)"),
        ApiModel(id: 2, apiName: "trainings/xx/0?cohort_id=\(cohortId)"),
        ApiModel(id: 3, apiName: "survey/get/xxx/0?cohort_id=\(cohortId)"),
        ApiModel(id: 4, apiName: "user/lowest/xxxx/0?cohort_id=\(cohortId)"),
    ]
    
    for item in apiItems {
        let data = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: getRequestConfig(endPoint: item.apiName))
        switch item.id  {
        case 1:
            let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode(ParticipantModel.self, from: data!)
            let items = decoder.response
            for item in items {
                let entity = ParticipantEntity(context: dataController.container.viewContext)
                entity.id = Int64(item.id)
                entity.first_name = item.first_name
                entity.last_name = item.last_name
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(items.count, forKey: "pCounts")
            dataController.save()
            print("Success Saving Participant Data")
        case 2:
            let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode(TrainingModel.self, from: data!)
            let items = decoder.response
            for item in items {
                let entity = TrainingEntity(context: dataController.container.viewContext)
                entity.training_id = Int64(item.training_id)
                entity.group_name = item.columns.group_name
                entity.group_id = Int16(item.columns.group_id ?? 0)
            }
            dataController.save()
            print("Success Saving Training Data")
        case 3:
            let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode(ParticipantVisitLogModel.self, from: data!)
            let items = decoder.response
            for item in items {
                let entity = ParticipantVisitLogEntity(context: dataController.container.viewContext)
                entity.id = Int16(item.id)
                entity.visit_id = Int16(item.visit_id)
                entity.type_of_survey = item.type_of_survey
                entity.survey_id = Int16(item.survey_id)
            }
            dataController.save()
            print("Success Saving Participant Visit Log Data")
        case 4:
            let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode(GroupModel.self, from: data!)
            let items = decoder.response
            for item in items {
                let entity = GroupEntity(context: dataController.container.viewContext)
                entity.id = Int16(item.id)
                entity.name = item.name
            }
            dataController.save()
            print("Success Group Data")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    print("DEFAULT")
    print("DONE CALLING ALL APIS..!")
    isMainLoading = false
}
```

Comment: How do I print the progress using async?, I tried it but its not updating.

 @State var apiCountIndex : Int = 0;

 var body: some View {

 if isMainLoading{
  CustomProgressView(apiIndex, totalApi)
 }
}